# Converting XML to an HTML-String using XSLT in Java

Tags: java, ajax, xml, xslt

I can now generate an HTML file using the code:

```
FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream("original.xml");  
FileInputStream xsl = new FileInputStream("converter.xsl");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.html");

Source xmlDoc =  new StreamSource(xml);
Source xslDoc =  new StreamSource(xsl);
Result result =  new StreamResult(out);

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();            
Transformer trans = factory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
trans.transform(xmlDoc, result);
```

However, I want to generate a Java String instead of an external HTML file, so that I can pass the result back to my JSP page by Ajax callback. How can I modify this code to do that?

Comment: There's nothing in your code that specifies that HTML is what comes out (except perhaps the name of the output file).  It all comes down to the XSL file - what it converts your XML into.  With a different XSL file, this could generate something completely different.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well that's true. What I'm wondering about is how to replace that FileOutputStream with some String thing. It seems that the construction of StreamResult is very restricted.

Comment: @goldfrapp04: Have you tried the ByteArrayOutputStream below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `FileOutputStream` with a `StringWriter`, then call `toString()` on the `StringWriter` at the end.  Something like this.

```
FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream("original.xml");  
FileInputStream xsl = new FileInputStream("converter.xsl");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

Source xmlDoc =  new StreamSource(xml);
Source xslDoc =  new StreamSource(xsl);
Result result =  new StreamResult(writer);

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();            
Transformer trans = factory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
trans.transform(xmlDoc, result); 

String outputString = writer.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the type of variable *out* to ByteArrayOutputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.toString() // Should do the job
```